# How to convert a float value into an array of quint16?

Tags: c++, qt, casting

I'm working in developing an emulator of an equipment that sends its floating data in 2 memory spaces of quint16. Upon arrival at the server, the array of quint16 is processed as follows:

```
float Convert::toFloat(quint16 *value)
{
    quint32 outValue;
    quint32 q1 = (value[1])&0x0000ffff;
    quint32 q2 = (value[0]<<16)&0xffff0000;
    float v_value=0;

    outValue = (q2)|q1;

    memcpy(&v_value,&outValue,sizeof(float));

    if (std::isnan(v_value)){
        v_value = 0;
    }

    if (std::isinf(v_value)){
        v_value = 0;
    }

    return v_value;
}

//In code
quint16 ReadResponseTable[MD_TCP_READ_TABLE_SIZE];

//fill ReadResponseTable

Convert::toFloat(&this->ReadResponseTable[MD_TCP_RELATIVE_ADDR_CH1+i*2])
```

Now what I need to do in developing the emulator is the opposite of the above: I need a function that gets float data and converts it to quint16* so I can send it to the server. Problem is I don't know how to do that; I'm terrible with bit operation. I searched SO and others but their answers were at best how to convert float into a single quint16, never making the two memory spaces separation. Many attempts using QDataStream or direct cast or memcpy failed as well (testing by converting a float into quint16 and back with the function above and it never getting the original number). So any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please add major / preffered programming language tag

Comment: @umlcat done. I forgot that people don't necessarily know quint16 is a Qt typedef :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <QDataStream>
#include <QBuffer>
#include <QPair>

#include <QDebug>

static void setup_stream_helper(QDataStream &stream, 
    QDataStream::ByteOrder byteOrder, 
    QDataStream::FloatingPointPrecision floatingPrecision)
{
    stream.setByteOrder(byteOrder);
    stream.setFloatingPointPrecision(floatingPrecision);
}

// Forward conversion    
float toFloat(quint16 a, quint16 b,
    QDataStream::ByteOrder byteOrder,
    QDataStream::FloatingPointPrecision floatingPrecision)
{
    QDataStream stream;

    QBuffer buffer;
    buffer.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);

    stream.setDevice(&buffer);

    setup_stream_helper(stream, byteOrder, floatingPrecision);

    stream << a << b;
    qDebug() << buffer.buffer().toHex(' '); // control what bytes your really has

    buffer.seek(0);

    float ret = 0;

    stream >> ret;

    return ret;
}

// Backwards conversion
QPair<quint16, quint16> fromFloat(float val, 
    QDataStream::ByteOrder byteOrder,
    QDataStream::FloatingPointPrecision floatingPrecision)
{
    QDataStream stream;

    QBuffer buffer;
    buffer.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);

    stream.setDevice(&buffer);

    setup_stream_helper(stream, byteOrder, floatingPrecision);

    stream << val;
    qDebug() << buffer.buffer().toHex(' '); // control what bytes your really has

    buffer.seek(0);

    QPair<quint16, quint16> ret;

    stream >> ret.first >> ret.second;

    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    auto byteOrders = { QDataStream::LittleEndian, QDataStream::BigEndian };
    auto floatingPrecision = QDataStream::SinglePrecision;

    qDebug() << "float -> quint16 ->float test:";

    float floats[] = { 0, -100.0, 123.123, -456.789, FLT_MAX, FLT_MIN, -FLT_MAX };

    for(QDataStream::ByteOrder byteOrder : byteOrders)
    {
        for(float val : floats)
        {
            qDebug() << "source float val =" << val;

            QPair<quint16, quint16> pair = fromFloat(val, byteOrder, floatingPrecision);
            qDebug() << "converted to quint16 pair =" << pair;

            float newVal = toFloat(pair.first, pair.second, byteOrder, floatingPrecision);
            qDebug() << "converted backwards to float val =" << newVal;

            Q_ASSERT(qFuzzyCompare(newVal, val));

            qDebug() << "\n------------------";
        }
    }

    qDebug() << "\nbackwards, quint16 ->float -> quint16 test:";

    quint16 as[] = { 0, 10, 100, 1000, 99, 999, UINT16_MAX};
    quint16 bs[] = { 5, 15, 55, 125, 555, 777, 0};

    for (QDataStream::ByteOrder byteOrder : byteOrders)
    {
        for (quint16 a : as)
        {
            for (quint16 b : bs)
            {
                QPair<quint16, quint16> pair(a, b);
                qDebug() << "sourse quint16 pair =" << pair;

                float val = toFloat(pair.first, pair.second, byteOrder, floatingPrecision);
                qDebug() << "converted to float val =" << val;

                QPair<quint16, quint16> newPair = fromFloat(val, byteOrder, floatingPrecision);
                qDebug() << "pair quint16 conveted backwards =" << newPair;

                Q_ASSERT(newPair == pair);

                qDebug() << "\n------------------";
            }
        }
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways. I tell you my favorite. You can convert float to shorts and viceversa :-)

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

union {
    struct {
        quint16 lo;
        quint16 hi;
    };
    float flt;
} converter;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    converter.flt = 1234.56;
    qDebug() << "lo short" << hex << converter.lo;
    qDebug() << "hi short" << hex << converter.hi;
    // lo short 51ec
    // hi short 449a

    converter.lo = 0xabcd;
    converter.hi = 0x4567;
    qDebug() << "float:" << converter.flt;
    // float: 3706.74

    return 0;
}
```

Check the results [here](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html).

EDIT: The above solution is a hack, and depends on the compiler allowing and working in a certain way, that we know is not blessed by the standards. Nevertheless, major compilers like current GCC and MSVC implementations not only do not warn or complain at all, but the resulting program works, is faster, and uses less memory than the alternatives. The major risks are that one day you upgrade your compiler and the program stops compiling, or even working. The other risk is that publishing that code on a social network warrants immediate downvotes.

The alternative way, recommended by the guardians of orthodoxy, is also a hack, but much less anarchist.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <cstring>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    float aux = 0;
    quint16 arr[2] = {0,0};
    Q_ASSERT(sizeof(aux) == sizeof(arr));

    aux = 1234.56f;
    std::memcpy(&arr, &aux, sizeof(arr));
    qDebug() << "float:" << aux << "quint16:" << hex << arr[0] << arr[1];
    // quint16: 51ec 449a

    arr[0] = 0xabcd;
    arr[1] = 0x4567;
    std::memcpy(&aux, &arr, sizeof(aux));
    qDebug() << "float:" << aux << "quint16:" << hex << arr[0] << arr[1];
    // float: 3706.74

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know that this is a hack, and assumes a lot about memory layout and endianess that makes it not very portable. But I guess that you can apply this to your emulator, at least for most common computers.

Comment: Well it worked! :) Thanks! But since as you sad your answer is a 'hack' and there are other ways, I won't mark it as the right answer yet to stimulate others to come with those other methods as well.

Comment: Type punning via unions is not permitted in C++, reading from an inactive union member is undefined behavior.  Use `memcpy` (which after optimization is just as efficient almost 100% of the time, and will not break strict aliasing rules in the compiler's dataflow analysis)